# how to fix spurious runtime errors in Visual Studio 2010 javascript debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2010, javascript-debugger

I'm getting a spurious javascript `runtime error: Function expected` in VS2010 with IE10, and the debugger is halting on a commented-out line, not even on a line of actual code.  The page runs fine in Firefox/Firebug.

Is there any way to "reset" the debugger or to reset the simulated IIS environment in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem before- VS was stopping on a commented out line in a javascript file. This is how I fixed it in IE11: Press F12 to open the development tools. Choose the Network tab (looks like a wi-fi router), then select the button for "Always refresh from server". This does what it says: ignore the cache and get the current file. Oddly, clearing the cache had no effect, but turning this setting on did the trick.